# Ocultar link do download

Tags: php, download

Estou com uma dificuldade, fiz um sistema que libera download de arquivo para cada usuário especifico, essa verificação é feita pelo código do usuário logado e filtros de mês e ano que o usuário preenche, então necessariamente a pessoa tem que estar logado para gerar esse link, porem uma vez que a pessoa faz o download qualquer um pode utilizando esse link fazer o download novamente do arquivo e era isso que eu não queria, eu gostaria que esse link ficasse oculto, tem alguma forma de fazer isso?

```
<?php
$pasta = '/arquivos';
$arquivos = "$user->cod_func".'  '.utf8_decode($_POST['select_mes']).' de '.$_POST['select_ano'].'.pdf';
$filename = 'arquivos/'.$arquivos;

if (file_exists($filename)) {
?>  
Download do Arquivo: <a href="?action=download&file=<?php echo base64_encode("$pasta/$arquivos"); ?>"><?php echo $_POST['select_mes'].' '.$_POST['select_ano']; ?></a>
<br>
Vizualizar: <a href="?action=embed&file=<?php echo base64_encode("$pasta/$arquivos"); ?>"><?php echo $_POST['select_mes'].' '.$_POST['select_ano']; ?></a>
<br>

<?php
} else {
echo "Não existe holerith no mês selecionado";
}
?>
```

Comment: Você pode fazer a mesma validação na página do download, só liberando o download caso de tudo certo. E seria bom não passar o caminho do arquivo, usa algum código para identificar.

Comment: Exatamente isso que quero como mascarar esse endereço na hora de fazer o download, a validação do usuário é feita pelo joomla ai no PHP eu só pego a sessão, mas mesma validando ele por ai só restringe se eu acessar o php direto se eu acessar o link gerado ele ainda baixa o arquivo

Answer (score 0):

Duas alternativas:

A primeira e mais fácil é ao entrar nessa página onde tem o link para download, você salva na sessão o arquivo que vai se baixado. O link não precisa mais desse parâmetro, pode ser somente /download.
Nesse /download, por exemplo, você verifica se existe algum arquivo na sessão e se houver, você envia esse arquivo que nem você faz no link atual, mas isso impede ele abrir duas páginas iguais a essa.

A outra alternativa é você criar uma tabela com o uma key gerada de forma aleatória (chave primária), oid do usuário e o arquivo para download.
Ao entrar nessa página você cria esse registro e na url, ao invés de passar o parâmetro file, você pode passar a key e lá na outra página buscar o arquivo pela key no banco de dados e retornar o arquivo para download.